# How to make page non scrollable, but only table within scrollable?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website that displays files from a database. My goal is to display those files to something similar to google drive's layout with their table and make the page non-scrollable, only the table. Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpOZ2.jpg

With my attempts using `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0%;` it won't go to the bottom and the site is breaking. Any ideas of to achieve this?

Here is my code right now:

```css
table{
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.tbl-header{
    background-color: #eee;
}
.tbl-content{
    height: 700px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin-top: 0;

    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
}
th{
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-align: left;

    color: dimgray;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
td{
    padding: 8px 18px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;

    color: dimgray;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
```

```html
<section class="userFiles-section">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                   <div class="tbl-header">
                       <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                           <thead>
                               <tr>
                                   <th>Name</th>
                                   <th>Upload Date</th>
                                   <th>File Size</th>
                                   <th>Download</th>
                                   <th>Delete</th>
                               </tr>
                           </thead>
                       </table>
                   </div>
                   <div class="tbl-content">
                       <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                           <tbody>
                           @files.map { file =>
                               <tr>
                                   <td>@file.getFilename</td>
                                   <td>@file.getUploadDate</td>
                                   <td>@file.getSize</td>
                                   <td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 21px;">cloud_download</i></button></td>
                                   <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 21px;">delete_forever</i></button></td>
                               </tr>
                           }
                           </tbody>
                       </table>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
        </section>
```

/ noxx

Comment: could you please provide more specific question related to general scala? it looks like this is more related to playframework / html or javascript

Comment: Yeah you right, I remove the scala tag. oh oliver did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make all the elements fit into the page width and height, and make the table container also fit into the page with a fixed position, then make it scrollable.

```
div.tbl-content {
    position: fixed;
    /* Adjust these values to 
    make the table fit within its 
    allocated space */
    top: 100px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 200px;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: With little adjustments i got it! Thanks.